# socket programming : tcp_client "gai" error

Tags: python, serversocket, tcpsocket

I'm setting up a simple client socket (my server socket works well). But I'm stuck by a lil bug. here's my code and here's the error. Can't find this error nowhere on the web.

```
from socket import *
import sys 
host=socket.gethostname()
#host=127.0.0.1
serverPort= 12345
clientSocket =socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((127.0.0.1,serverPort))
msg= raw_input("Input text here:")
clientSocket.send(msg)
modmsg= clientSocket.recv(1024)
print "from server", modmsg
clientSocket.close()
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcp_client.py", line 5, in <module>
    clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: : |   ../tooshort

Comment: oh, it should be a very simple set up i presumed. Ive seen eg in  books that are jus a short

Comment: The error traceback `clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))` does not match the code `clientSocket.connect(host,serverPort)`.  Please post the real code you use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect here (did you post the real code you ran?):

1. host cannot be empty
2. `connect` takes 1 argument and it's a tuple
3. if you do `from socket import *`, you cannot do `socket.socket`

fixed:

```
import socket
import sys
host=socket.gethostname()
serverPort= 12345
clientSocket = socket.socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((host,serverPort))
msg= raw_input("Input text here:")
clientSocket.send(msg)
modmsg= clientSocket.recv(1024)
print "from server", modmsg
clientSocket.close()
```

now I get proper timeout when I run this code (I don't have the client) instead of your error.

Comment: Thanks. I made the recommended changes and got the same error. I've been tweaking the code inorder for a successful exe...  I think the host is the issue as the error says "gai"